Migrate Angular 17 build from webpack to esbuild
Our project was using:
"builder": @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser
for our build.
In our webpack.config.js we have this plugin:
 /**
     * report-result.js cannot be tree-shaked as part of the bundling process, since it actually runs as an global script.
     * an empty stub file will be used to help reduce bundle size and improvement performance.
     */
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /(.*)proto\/report-result(.*)/,
        function (resource) {
            if (targetOptions.configuration === 'production') {                    
                resource.request = resource.request.replace(
                    /report-result/,
                    'report-result-stub',
                );
            }
        },
    ),

Now we have migrated to Angular 17 and want to use the deafault Angular CLI with this: "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application" (which is esbuild).
The question is, how can we achive the same functionality as we have in our webpack NormalModuleReplacementPlugin ?
As far as I can see, Angular does not allow you to customize esbuild or use plugins at all.
Thanks!

any news for this question ?
